# differentiation using quotient rule

Tags: calculus

The quotient rule, i've understood as ${vdu - udv}\over v^2$

Differentiating $1 \over x+1$ it's ${(x+1)(0)-(1)(1)}\over (x+1)^2$ which equals $-1 \over (x+1)^2$

Differentiating $-x \over x+1$ it's ${(x+1)(-1)-(-x)(1)}\over (x+1)^2$ which equals $-1 \over (x+1)^2$

Why are these the same, or rather, what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\frac{-x}{x+1}=\frac{-x-1+1}{x+1}=-1+\frac{1}{x+1}$$

They differ by a constant, hence the derivative is the same.

Alternative working:

$$\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{-x}{x+1}=\frac{x+1}{x+1}=1$$

Comment: thank you, that helped.